# List Events Trigger - Firebase / GCF

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to execute a Google Cloud Function, but just when the user has completed some events list (Analytics). It doesn't needs to be in order...

Ex: Buy Product, Sell Product, Make a comment on an product.

When all these steps was completed, I need to trigger a function.

There is away to do that directly, without an auxiliar table?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions has [event-based triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers#events) and it allows you to manage one trigger per function after all the the events are done regardless of the order.

You may try that by using a master endpoint that allows you to track whether the events were completed. The master endpoint may check whether the events have been completed (such as by calling their endpoints) and track them as they complete (such as by having the events’  endpoints return a confirmation value).

Then when all events are completed, the master endpoint can send the HTTP trigger on the Function.